# How to Generate a Presigned S3 URL via AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

Is there a way to create presigned URL for objects in S3 bucket using AWS CLI?

I know that could be done using SDK, but is it possible with CLI?

I found this on one of the AWS docs, but can't complete the command:

```
s3cmd signurl s3://BUCKET/OBJECT <expiry_epoch|+expiry_offset>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Did you try [aws s3 presign](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/presign.html)?

> Generate a pre-signed URL for an Amazon S3 object. This allows anyone
>   who receives the pre-signed URL to retrieve the S3 object with an HTTP
>   GET request. For sigv4 requests the region needs to be configured
>   explicitly.

This will generate a URL that will expire in 3600 seconds (default)

```
aws s3 presign s3://mybucket/myobject
```

This will generate a URL that will expire in 300 seconds

```
aws s3 presign s3://mybucket/myobject  --expires-in 300
```

Output

```
https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/myobject?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&Expires=1503602631&Signature=ibOGfAovnhIF13DALdAgsdtg2s%3D
```

Comment: I am trying this for the first time.

I don't know how do we create signed urls for S3 objects using AWS CLI.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Will check.
So the maximum time one can have is 7 days?

Comment: So then can you give access to upload to a specific folder with this?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for PUT or POST but maybe I'm doing something wrong.  Docs only suggest GET, but maybe there is another way to accomplish this with the CLI.

Comment: This needs more attention on teh interwebs Thanks @helloV. Wish I'd have seen it earlier.

Answer (score 5):

Wildcards are now supported.

E.g.  `aws s3 presign s3://mybucket/*`

Comment: AFAICT, it will make the presign link, but it's invalid.

Answer (score 2):

@Michael and @Shabbir,

Yes, `aws s3 presign` does not accept globbing/wildcards/, `--include`, `--exclude`, or `--recursive`.
aws `ls` does not accept `-1`; it behaves as `ls -lp` or `ls -lph`.

a loop works:

```
for file in $(aws s3 ls s3://mybucket --profile myprofile \
--endpoint-url <my-endpoint> | awk '{print $NF}'); do
    aws s3 presign --expires-in 300 "s3://mybucket/$file" |
    --profile my-profile --endpoint-url <my-endpoint>
done
```

Answer (score 2):

if you do `aws s3 presign s3://bucket-address/my-file.csv`

you get back url. Then when you pass it to `wget` make sure you wrap it with apostrophes

```
wget 'https://bucket-address.s3.aws.com/xbxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

if you just do without apostrophes you will get 403 `wget https://bucket-address.s3.aws.com/xbxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

I'm describing more in https://blog.eq8.eu/til/transfer-file-to-server.html

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, but that is nothing new there in the context of this question. The issue with quotes in merely an issue in relation to the `&` and how that in interpreted by the shell. It might not be an issue in another shell, way windows command line.

Answer (score 1):

So the command for pre-signed URL is:

```
aws s3 presign s3://bucket-address/  --expires-in 300
```

But the caveat is; we can have pre-signed URL's that works for individual file/object level and not on directory level.

Happy to be corrected if wrong.

Comment: It sort of appears that you can't  generate a pre-signed url for a bucket.

Comment: Yes, `aws s3 presign` does not accept globbing/wildcards/, `--include`, `--exclude`, or `--recursive'.
aws `ls` does not accept `-1`; it behaves as `ls -lp` or `ls -lph`.

a loop works:
```
for file in $(aws s3 ls s3://mybucket --profile myprofile --endpoint-url <my-endpoint> | awk '{print $NF}'); do
    aws s3 presign --expires-in 300 "s3://mybucket/$file" --profile my-profile --endpoint-url <my-endpoint>
done
```