# Decryption of encrypted S3 file using aws-encryption-cli --decrypt

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am looking for a way to decrypt an already encrypted file using `aws-encryption-cli --decrypt.`

Is there a way I can specify the encrypted S3 object location? I am using role based decryption where the current role has permission to decrypt the object even if i do not specify the KMS key.

I was trying to use below command:

`aws-encryption-cli --decrypt --input s3://XXX/encryptedfile.text  --encryption-context purpose=test --metadata-output ~/metadata --output .`

Could you please help if you know about encryption/decryption using `aws-cli`

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

you have an option with **`AWS CLI`** [AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html)

- **For encryption :**

Below command for upload your file or object with **`KMS KEY`** Please refer [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46902348/how-to-upload-files-to-s3-from-aws-cli-with-kms-encryption)

`aws s3 cp /home/ubuntu/Desktop/abc_count.png s3://mybucket/abc_count.png --sse aws:kms --sse-kms-key-id (KMS KEY with arn)`

---

- **For Decrypt:**

Below command for ***`Decrypt`*** file/object or download ***`Encrypted`*** file refer this [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/presign.html) and also refer [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45869240/aws-s3-pre-signed-url-via-cli) for get ***`presign URL`***

**Use command :**
`aws s3 presign s3://mybucket/abc_count.png`

you get presign URL for access uploaded file/object

**Output :** `https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/abc_count.png?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&Expires=1503602631&Signature=ibOGfAovnhIF13DALdAgsdtg2s%3D`

than you can directly [download](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207265/how-to-download-a-file-from-a-website-via-terminal) ***`Encrypted`*** file/object using below command :

`wget -P /home/ubuntu/Desktop/abc_count1.png "your presign URL"`

Hope it will work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Let me try this